# Unicode and console interpretation

Tags: java, unicode, console

I print to the standard output some characters from a wide UTF-8 range in a Java application. My console is configured for UTF-8 support. My problem is that sometimes, when I decide to print 10 characters for example, I see a number of character which is less then 10.

I think this is due to the console which interprets some characters. Are there some unicode character which can be interpreted like: erase the previous character ? Is it possible to exclude them from the ouput (what are the codepoints of these characters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using carriage return or the backspace character you can get results like you describe. This little test program for instance...

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("abc\rdef\u0008g");
    }
}
```

...prints in my terminal (ubuntu)

```
$ java Test
deg
$
```

`\r` is carriage return, and `\u0008` represents the backspace character. (Carriage return sends the cursor back to the first column, and backspace sends it back one column.)

---

To remove all these, so called "control characters" you could do:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");
```

from [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> `\p{Cntrl}`      A control character: [\x00-\x1F\x7F]

Comment: I removed these characters from the ouput with myString.replaceAll("[\r\u0008]", ""). However, I still get some truncated output. I think there are other characters :(

Answer (score 0):

Obvious one is [backspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace)